# C# How do I run a Linked List's delete method from the main program?

Tags: c#, list, methods

I have a user-made linked list (no LINQ).
I have items in them but I want to delete some.

The delete method of my Linked List:

```
public void Delete(ListElem elem)
    {
        ListaElem helper = null;
        ListaElem prev = null;
        while (helper != elem)
        {
            prev = helper;
            helper = helper.next;
        }

        prev.next = elem.next;
    }
```

After this I want to delete a specific element from this List but how do I call it?

Comment: You just invoke the method on the object you instantiated? Wherever you are creating the objects and inserting them into the list, you can store them as a reference and then try to delete them later.

Comment: Let's say I iterate throught the list and want to delete a specific element that contains the string I want to delete. How do I call the delete method on it?

Comment: What kind of object is ListElem?

Comment: It has a string field. I want to delete the ListElem that's object has the specific string field in it.

Comment: That method would always throw a null reference exception.  If `elem` is `null` then it skips the `while` loop and `prev` is still `null` and `prev.next = elm.next;` will fail.  Otherwise it would crash on `helper = helper.next;`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your class is called `CustomLinkedList`

At some point in your code, you have instantiated the class:

```
CustomLinkedList myList = new CustomLinkedList();
```

Next, you've added some elements to it:

```
ListElem elem1 = new ListElem();
myList.Add(elem1);
```

In order to delete an element, all you have to do is say:

```
myList.Delete(elem1);
```

Now, what if you want to search the object for an element that has a certain field, perhaps a name? You need another method, define it like this:

```
public ListElem Find(String name){
   // For every item in my list, look for one that has a name that matches.
}
```

Now you can find a particular item and then delete it.

Comment: I'll check this out now. The difference is that my insert method takes these objects and places them in the list. So I let the program do it to himself, so i'm not able to refer to the ListElems by their names

Comment: And can you help me how can I analyze the string field of my object while iterating through the ListElems, cause elem.Name doesn't work.

Comment: Without knowing the exact way your data structure is written, I can only offer the generic advice. `elem.Name` was just an example for a field you could search by.